# Not able to replace the ↵ symbol in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/i530eYukNmic1TCcZ2Yb?p=preview)

I want to replace carriage returns with a space so that users can type (The ↵ is the user hitting enter):

```
These↵

are↵

some↵

words.
```

And it will convert into:

```
These are some words.
```

Then I want to make an array out of those words using .split(). So the desired output should be:

```
["These", "are", "some", "words."]
```

The output I am receiving is:

```
["These↵are↵some↵words."]
```

Comment: What you tried `myString = myString.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "<br />");`?

Comment: This matches: https://regex101.com/r/wK5kA8/1

Comment: Do you mean the '↵ ' symbol eg: https://regex101.com/r/rZ2lK8/1 or are you on about newlines /  carriage returns (https://regex101.com/r/uG4zX5/1)?

Comment: This question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic). Update your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: I will update the problem so everyone can reproduce the problem. Just give me one moment. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Check [this site](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) to convert the string into hex values and see what you really have to deal with.

Comment: @zzzzBov I made an edit to my question that has a better explanation and reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Scott, please re-read the on-hold message and update your question appropriately.

Comment: From what you say, `$scope.inputReplaced = $scope.input.replace(/\n/g, ' ');` should work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you just need to match linebreaks (as `↵` are the result of users pressing ENTER), you can use

```
$scope.inputReplaced = $scope.input.replace(/\n/g, ' ');
```

Or (to match 1+ consecutive linebreaks)

```
$scope.inputReplaced = $scope.input.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, ' ');
```

See [this updated Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LjL6K1RGrWX6dgWcSBOy?p=preview)